# Is it necessary to put id field in table,for not getting "No identifier specified for entity"

Tags: hibernate, annotations

Iam getting "No identifier specified for entity:" error,i didnt put id field in table,Is this necessary to put id field in table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every entity must have a unique identifier. It doesn't have to be an auto-generated number, it can be a natural identifier, or a combination of fields, but it must exist.